# Created this simple code to draw circle in android and it shows nothing on emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created this simple code in android and it shows nothing on emulator it should show a circle. Do I have to edit something in the `xml` file also?

Here my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Circlexy ourview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourview = new Circlexy(this);
        setContentView(ourview);
    }
}
```

And this is my `Circlexy` class:

```
public class Circlexy extends View {
    Bitmap ball;
    public Circlexy (Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint= new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,100,paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your circlexy class;

Comment: oops haha let me edit it.

Comment: are you creating xml component with this view...

Comment: its just a custom class....so do i need changes in my xmlfile..???...shouldn't setContnetview automatically the code in circlexy class..??

Comment: @PuneetSharma the code is working fine. I got a blue circle on my screen.

Comment: its not showing on my emulator..:( so emulator issue..??

Comment: First of all you are passing the Activity instance in the onCreate of Activity and at that time Activity doesn't have any view so its not getting visible. Its becoming kind of cyclic dependency.

Comment: @PuneetSharma Just check if you are loading the correct `Activity`. Also a tip, move `Paint paint= new Paint();` outside `onDraw`.

Comment: @zeus how do i resolve this..??

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal can u show me your xml layout file

Comment: @PuneetSharma The `Circlexy` class is the view. So there is no xml layout file.

Comment: yeah i know...?? but its confusing me how such a simple code isn't showing

Comment: it worked i don't know what happened but it just drew upon restarting emulator

Comment: @PuneetSharma Happy coding. :)

Comment: its stopped working again...and i did not do anything the log says too much output to process i noticed skipping frame

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a layout to your Activity and hence any change you do , be in programmatic or in xml , you would not be able to see it.

The setContentView() Method is used to set the layout (xml) file to the present activity but you're passing your circle View to it, You should set the content as the xml file using the "R" reference.
Something like :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Where, your activity xml is named activity_main.xml

Also , on another Note , You Should Also Update Your Circlexy Class to include other constructors for good practice.

```
public class Circlexy extends View {


public Circlexy(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Circlexy(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Circlexy(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint= new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, 100, paint);
 }

}
```

Comment: I found the problem ! you need to set the layout of the activity in the setContentView() method ,like setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), You're actually not seeting the layout of your activity correctly.

Comment: but i want to set the new view i created as my default view..??? R>layout.activity_main just sets my xml layout  as my view

Comment: the view does not contain a canvas yet , think of it like this , keep a blank a  activity_main.xml with just the root element , this will serve as a canvas to the activity. It's like you're trying to draw a circle on a sheet of paper but you dont have a sheet of paper yet , where will the onDraw() draw (without any rerfrencing xml)? there is no layout attached to the activity , you have to attach a layout to an *activity* for the sheet of paper(canvas) to be available, be it blank.

Comment: i tried its not working...its says launcher stopped working

Comment: Can you post your activity_main.xml and the error in detail too ?

Comment: also a person above had my code working ..?? so theres that ....canvas is drawn by default when i call the extends view in my cricleclass

Comment: lol i just solved it i dont know what happened but it just drew itself.

Comment: Great to hear that !  please post the working solution to help someone who might search for a similar problem.

Comment: it sopped working and i didnot edit anything ....logcat says sometimes too much output to process.

Comment: can you please upload your code on any git repository ? i still think it is a problem with xml/setContentView.

Though I would strongly suggest to test on a different emulator or better still a device before uploading.

Comment: OK i solved it for properly this time i just alloacted more processing power to emulator